# Angular directive to replace external links

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, angularjs-directive

How can i create a custom filter to replace:

```
<a href="http://www.externalsite.com">Whatever text</a>
```

into this:

```
<a href="#" ng-click="openExternal('http://www.externalsite.com')">Whatever text</a>
```

it should be easy, but i'm unable to do it… I have this:

```
<div ng-bind-html="item.htmltext | myFilter"></div>
```

and item.htmltext contains some  tags that i want to replace that way… How should i create myFilter to replace the links?

Comment: I don't remember how to get the parameter from the directive, so I won't answer. But having such JS code into the directive wouldn't be enough to redirect?    `window.location = "http://www.yoururl.com";`

Comment: I forgot to say that i'm using <div ng-bind-html="item.htmltext"></div> so my be it's a filter what i need….

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**EDIT 2:**

There is a solution without `$watch`: http://jsfiddle.net/33jQz/18/

Directive priority is set to -1 (beacuse priority of ngBindHtml is 0), and logic is run in next `$digest` cycle by using `$timeout` service.

**EDIT 1:**

You can use directive which replace child `a` node in your div. It sets `$watch` checking length of new `<a>` elements inside your div, then it cuts `href` attribute and adds new attribute - `ng-click="open()"`. At the and it use `$compile` service on element to make `ng-click` works.

```
angular.module('ui.directives', []).directive('changeUrl', function ($compile) {
    return {
        restrict: 'A',
        scope: true,
        link: function (scope, elem, attrs) {

            scope.$watch(function () {
                return elem.children('a').length;
            }, function () {
                if (elem.children('a').length > 0) {
                    replace();
                }
            });

            function replace() {
                var href = elem.children('a').attr('href');
                elem.children('a').attr('href', null);
                elem.children('a').attr('ng-click', 'open(\''+href+'\')');
                $compile(elem.contents())(scope);

            }
            scope.open = function (url) {
                alert(url);
            }
        }
    }
});
```

Because of using `$watch` it should work with your external html content passed to ng-bind-html.

There is a jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/33jQz/13/

Old answer:

<strike>You can create a directive which will replace your `<a href>` with a new one</strike>

```
angular.module('ui.directives', []).directive('changeUrl', function () {
    return {
        restrict: 'A',
        scope: true,
        template: '<span><a ng-click="open()" ng-transclude></a></span>',
        replace: true,
        transclude: true,
        link: function (scope, elem, attrs) {
            var href = attrs.href;
            scope.open = function(){
                alert(href);    
            }
        }
    }
});
```

Using:

```
<a change-url href="http://www.externalsite.com">Whatever text</a>
```

JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/33jQz/8/

Comment: Problem is that i can't add the change-url to my content. As i've said it's displayed this way: <div ng-bind-html="item.htmltext | myFilter"></div> so item.htmltext contains the html data (from restangular)

Comment: I've updated my answer. It may need some improvements but should work.

Comment: It works but it's a waste of watches if the HTML text contains a lot of links. There isn't any way to make this only once? May be destroying the watches after replace?

Comment: `ng-bind-html` has priority 0, so your directive should be run later. You have to also use `$timeout` to render your content in next `$digest` cycle. There is updated fiddle without `$watch`: http://jsfiddle.net/33jQz/18/

Answer (score 0):

I've found another solution using lodash to replace all a tag elements:

```
angular.module('module').directive('changeUrl', function ($compile, $timeout) {
return {
    priority: -1,
    restrict: 'A',
    scope: true,
    link: function (scope, elem, attrs) {
        $timeout(function() {
        var links = elem.find('a');
            _.map(links, function (a) {
                var href = a.href;
                a.setAttribute('ng-click', 'openUrl(\'' + href + '\')');
                a.removeAttribute('href');
            });
            $compile(elem.contents())(scope);
        });
    }
}
```

});